# How to fix the "npm install error" when installing "Botkit"?

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, installation, botkit

I am a newbie machine learning programmer trying get how to install the botkit tool for creating AI messaging bots from the bot kit studio.
Botkit was installed but the following errors are shown in my terminal:

```
    Rakeshs-MacBook-Air:~ niharika$ npm install
    npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/niharika/package.json'
    npm WARN niharika No description
    npm WARN niharika No repository field.
    npm WARN niharika No README data
    npm WARN niharika No license field.
    Rakeshs-MacBook-Air:~ niharika$ npm install --productions
    npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/niharika/package.json'
    npm WARN niharika No description
    npm WARN niharika No repository field.
    npm WARN niharika No README data
    npm WARN niharika No license field.
```

I can't seem to figure out what the `package.json` file is supposed to be in order to run botkit studio.

Comment: did you try `npm install --save botkit` ?

Comment: You say that "Botkit was installed". So what are you trying to install now then?

Answer (score 0):

This error does not have much to do with Botkit, but more to do with where you are running the npm install.  You are running it in your `/Users/niharika` path.  If you cloned down botkit into that directory then you will need to `cd` into it first. Your path will look more like `/Users/niharika/botkitslackstarter/`. Then run `npm install` which will look for a `package.json` in the root and install all dependencies so then you will be able to run `node bot.js` to start the application.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

```
npm install
```

Step 2:

```
npm install botkit
```